# selecionar dados de acordo com as datas

Tags: r

Olá !

Como faço para selecionar as linhas de um `data.frame` de acordo com algumas datas ?

ex: selecionar os dados da `coluna 2` para as datas `2016/12/15, 2016/12/25, 2017/01/08, 2018/01/01.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primeiro eu crio um `data.frame` com duas colunas, `coluna1` (contendo valores aleatórios) e `coluna2` contendo algumas datas.

```
dados <- data.frame(coluna1 = rnorm(10), coluna2 = as.Date(c("2016/12/15", "2016/12/20", "2016/12/25", "2016/12/30", "2017/01/05", "2017/01/08", 2018/01/01", "2018/12/31", "2017/11/25", "2017/11/30")))
```

Separo as datas de interesse:

```
datas <- as.Date(c("2016/12/15", "2016/12/25", "2017/01/08", "2018/01/01"))
```

Utilizo o comando `%in%` para selecionar as datas da `coluna2` que contém as datas de interesse

```
dados$coluna1[dados$coluna2%in%datas]
```